# A blank page appears on running the android application

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I am making an android application on Movies.I am using Volley library and Glide to load the dynamic data and RecyclerView to display the content. There is no compile time or runtime error.The problem is when I run the application a white page displays on the screen with no output.

Below is the snapshot of the output:

[click to view output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reZby.png)

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private final String JSON_URL = 


"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/
aws1994/f583d54e5af8e56173492d3f60dd5ebf/raw
/c7796ba51d5a0d37fc756cf0fd14e54434c547bc/anime.json" ;

private JsonArrayRequest request ;
private RequestQueue requestQueue ;
private List<Anime> lstAnime ;
private RecyclerView recyclerView ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lstAnime = new ArrayList<>() ;
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
    jsonrequest();



}

private void jsonrequest() {

    request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, 
    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {


                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i) ;
                    Anime anime = new Anime() ;
                    anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));

                   anime.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                    anime.setRating(jsonObject.getString("Rating"));
                    anime.setCategories(jsonObject.getString("categories"));
                    anime.setNb_episode(jsonObject.getInt("episode"));
                    anime.setStudio(jsonObject.getString("studio"));
                    anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("img"));
                    lstAnime.add(anime);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(request) ;


}

private void setuprecyclerview(List<Anime> lstAnime) {


    RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,lstAnime) ;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

}
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{

private Context mContext;
private List<Anime> mData;
RequestOptions option;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Anime> mData)
{
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;

    //request option for glide imageview
    option = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);

}
@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
    holder.tv_rating.setText(mData.get(position).getRating());
    holder.tv_studio.setText(mData.get(position).getStudio());
    holder.tv_category.setText(mData.get(position).getCategories());

    //load image from internet and setting it to the imageview using glide library

    Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getImage_url()).apply(option).into(holder.img_thumbnail);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView tv_name;
    TextView tv_rating;
    TextView tv_studio;
    TextView tv_category;
    ImageView img_thumbnail;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.anime_name);
        tv_rating = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        tv_studio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studio);
        tv_category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categories);
        img_thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }
}

}
```

AnimeActivity.java

```
public class AnimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anime);

    // hide the default actionbar
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    // Recieve data

    String name  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_name");
    String description = 
    getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_description");
    String studio = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_studio") ;
    String category = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_category");
    int nb_episode = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("anime_nb_episode") ;
    String rating = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_rating") ;
    String image_url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_img") ;

    // ini views

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = 
    findViewById(R.id.collapsingtoolbar_id);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true);

    TextView tv_name = findViewById(R.id.aa_anime_name);
    TextView tv_studio = findViewById(R.id.aa_studio);
    TextView tv_categorie = findViewById(R.id.aa_categorie) ;
    TextView tv_description = findViewById(R.id.aa_description);
    TextView tv_rating  = findViewById(R.id.aa_rating) ;
    ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.aa_thumbnail);

    // setting values to each view

    tv_name.setText(name);
    tv_categorie.setText(category);
    tv_description.setText(description);
    tv_rating.setText(rating);
    tv_studio.setText(studio);

    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(name);


    RequestOptions requestOptions = new 

 RequestOptions().centerCrop()
.placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);


    // set image using Glide
    Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(requestOptions).into(img);





}
}
```

Anime.java (Model Class)

```
public class Anime {

private String name ;
private String description;
private String rating ;
private int nb_episode;
private String image_url;
private String categories;
private String studio;

public Anime() {
}

public Anime(String name, String description, String rating, int nb_episode, String image_url, String categorie, String studio) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.nb_episode = nb_episode;
    this.image_url = image_url;
    this.categories = categories;
    this.studio = studio;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public int getNb_episode() {
    return nb_episode;
}

public String getImage_url() {
    return image_url;
}

public String getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public String getStudio() {
    return studio;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public void setNb_episode(int nb_episode) {
    this.nb_episode = nb_episode;
}

public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
    this.image_url = image_url;
}

public void setCategories(String categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}

public void setStudio(String studio) {
    this.studio = studio;
}

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sahil.moviesjam">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AnimeActivity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies 
    {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'

}
```

Comment: ,please add logcat.

Comment: There's no runtime/compiletime error. The logcat is empty.

Comment: You should post your xml layout ```R.layout.activity_main```

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer updated (: please check

Comment: Remove line "                    anime.setCategories(jsonObject.getString("categories"));" Rest your code is working fine

Comment: @AshishJohn Thanks alot! I am not able to mark your comment as answer :(

Comment: @SahilAnand Not a problem bro, issue should be resolved thats important. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your logcat carefully it shows `org.json.JSONException: No value for categories`

Replace your line with this line

```
anime.setCategories(jsonObject.getString("categorie"));
```

ANd also replace your modal class

```
private String categorie="";
//change key in whole modal class
```

It will works for you as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON parameter was wrong.
Replace the line:

```
anime.setCategories(jsonObject.getString("categories"));
```

with

```
anime.setCategories(jsonObject.getString("categorie"));
```